# SMB Mount To Windows Server Appears to Lock up. Any Ideas?

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, windows, samba

We are running CentOS 6.3 with all the latest updates. (Attempt to resolve this issue)
The Server I am trying to connect to is a Windows Server 2008 R2 box.  Though this applies to our old SBS'03 Box too.  I can mount the share, browse it all I want.  Copy stuff off of the share and it keeps chugging right along.  The issue arrives when my Zimbra server, or any other write operation for that matter, hits the share.  It works for a few min takes a fair amount of data, then the share seems to lockup.  If I go into Server Manager on the Windows box, find the session and kill it.  The drive reconnects and starts working perfectly again.  There are no real errors except that Linux starts issuing connection errors

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the debug level in the configuration?  And can you post the `smbd.log` output?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
As a sysadmin i see a lot of problems with shares when it comes to authentication and permissions. 
In my production environment i have a two factor authentication mechanism that don't allow me to use UNC between servers when i log with a 2factor user(it basically locks the user for trying).
How do you authenticate with your windows box?
Can you copy the line from fstab you use to mount the directory?
Also check the permissions on the windows box and list it here.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can see "mount error(12): Can’t allocate memory" on the windows server.

If this is the case:

```
Set the following registry key to ’1′:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache

and set the following registry key to ’3′:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size

net stop server
net start server
```

Source: 
http://jlcoady.net/windows/how-to-resolve-mount-error12-cannot-allocate-memory-windows-share